# Не выводится список recyclerView хотя данные отправляю

Tags: android, recyclerview

Пытаюсь сделать функцию прикрепления файлов к письму. В итоге получилось прикреплять файлы и отображать в списке их имена, чтобы можно было удалить в случае чего ненужный файл, но я решил немного изменить файловый менеджер из которого я выбираю файлы. В итоге теперь у меня файл прикрепляются и в письме их после отправки видно, а в процессе написания письма не видно уже прикрепленные файлы. Вот как я вывожу эти файлы:

```
private void getImages() {
        mNames.clear();
        adapter.updateNames(mNames);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        if (extras != null) {
            if (extras.containsKey("attached_files")) {
                for (int j = 0; j < Objects.requireNonNull(draft_files).size(); j++) {
                    mNames.add(draft_files.get(j));
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
                    JsonObject object = array.get(i).getAsJsonObject();
                    mNames.add(object.get("filename").toString().substring(1, object.get("filename").toString().length() - 1));
                }

                adapter = new AttachedFileAdapter(mNames, getApplicationContext());
                adapter.updateNames(mNames);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

            } else {
                for (int i = 0; i < ms.getArray().size(); i++) {

                    JsonObject object = ms.getArray().get(i).getAsJsonObject();
                    mNames.add(object.get("filename").toString().substring(1, object.get("filename").toString().length() - 1));
                    adapter.updateNames(mNames);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    Log.i("m", "-0");
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                }
            }
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < ms.getArray().size(); i++) {

                JsonObject object = ms.getArray().get(i).getAsJsonObject();
                mNames.add(object.get("filename").toString().substring(1, object.get("filename").toString().length() - 1));
                adapter.updateNames(mNames);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }


        }
    }
```

в итоге функция вызывается но ничего не выводится, хотя массив в себе имеет елементы, не могу понять что случилось, ведь вроде все нормально было. Для того чтобы выгрузить файл в массив я вызываю функцию:

```
public void uploadFiles(String name, String data) {
        JsonArray oldArray = ms.getArray();
        JsonObject object = new JsonObject();

        if (oldArray == null) {
            return;

        }

        for (int i = 0; i < oldArray.size(); i++) {
            JsonObject objectMS = oldArray.get(i).getAsJsonObject();
            if (objectMS.get("filename").getAsString().equals(name)) {
                return;
            }
        }


        try {
            object.addProperty("filename", name);
            object.addProperty("data", data);
            oldArray.add(object);

            ms.setArray(oldArray);

            getImages();


        } catch (JsonIOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }
```

тут тоже все нормально работает. Изменился только вывод уже прикрепленных файлов - он пропал. В чем может быть проблема и как она связана с тем что я изменил способ прикрепления файлов?

Comment: Не очень понятно. У вас проблема с RecyclerView, или какими-то системными фичами прикрепления файлов к письму из стороннего приложения, передаваемых через Intent?

Comment: Возможно надо просто поменять местами вот эти строки везде? `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, я честно говоря не понимаю что происходит, получается при изменении метода выбора файла не через диалог со списком а через onActivityResult я не могу передать данные в адаптер, я проследил до куда у меня идут данные и получается что в onBindViewHolder данные уже не доходят, а системных фич нету которые прикрепляют файл, это встроенный проводник я так понимаю

Comment: Т.е. проблема у вас в том, что вы не можете обновить адаптер данными, которые есть, в `onActivityResult`?

Comment: получается так, я честно говоря сам с трудом понимаю что не так идет, все сейчас так - после выбора файла (независимо от способа) он кодируется в base64 и кидается в массив, дальше у меня есть функция которая тянет из этого массива данные чтобы показать в списке, и один метод прикрепления файла позволяет заполнить список данными а второй почему-то нет, и я не могу понять почему

Comment: Я совсем не понимаю что у вас происходит) Кажется, вам надо локализовать проблему, убрав всё лишнее. Лишним, кажется, является упоминание файлов и всего такого. Возможно, стоит создать пустой проект и там из `onActivityResult` попытаться обновить адаптер простым строковым массивом. Если это получится - смотреть чем код отличается от вашего текущего.

Comment: а если попытаться локализовать проблему в текущем проекте, есть вероятность что у меня это получится?

Comment: Вероятность есть всегда) Надо просто аккуратно всё залоггировать/продебажить чтобы понять в каком месте поведение программы расходится с вашими ожиданиями. После этого почитать документацию и попытаться понять что же не так)

Comment: я понял, ладно буду пробовать, спасибо за помощь и ценные советы :)